# Getting logstash to run on Windows

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I downloaded the zip version of the logstash from [LogStash Download Link](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash)

I unziped it and ensured the folder path does not have any space. Also I ensured that the JDK 64bit is available in the path. But when I try to start logstash, I am getting  "could not find jruby in C:\ELK\logstash-6.1.3\vendor\jruby"
I am using 6.1.3 version

Comment: Have you tried running the setup.bat from the bin folder?

Comment: yes, even running setup gives the similar error. The only way out was to install the previous version of the logstash.

Comment: were you able to get logstash running? I am trying to get it running on windows 7 and get this error--  pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS